# Unable to create a session entity with actions-on-google-nodejs

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

whole day was trying to create a session entity for my intent with [actions-on-google-nodejs](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs). Unfortunately without any success.

I believe that the this library doesn't support entities in any way, which is a bit sad. Am I right?

During my research I found [this amazing post](https://blog.dialogflow.com/post/create-and-manage-entities-with-api/) which is explaining how to create and manage entities through API , however they are using [nodejs-dialogflow](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow)

Was considering using both libraries **actions-on-google-nodejs** and **nodejs-dialogflow**, but than when I'm catching the intent with **actions-on-google-nodejs**  the second library (**nodejs-dialogflow**) will not have idea about the content and etc.

After further research I found [the API documentation for sessions.entityTypes](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions.entityTypes) The "Try this API" works amazing with Google OAuth 2.0, however don't know how to authorize my server (express.js) with Google OAuth 2.0. I tried with API key but all the time I'm getting the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
```

}

Any suggestions how I can create a session entity for my intent?

The reason why I'm trying to use session entity is because the entity will change every couple of days and don't want to update the entity in dialogflow. My idea is to store it in DB (firebase) and on intent will validate if it match any of the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that the Session Entity must be set to the values you want *before* it is expected to be matched in an Intent. You probably should do this right when your Action starts, in your case. So if you have your "Welcome" intent, and a "State Option" intent, where the "Option" entity is in the "State Option" intent, you should update "Option" in the "Welcome" intent. You can't do it in the "State Option" intent, because it needs to have matched the Entity already.

The two libraries do completely different things, and can work well together. You will need to get the session path from the original request body, which you can get from `conv.request` using the a-o-g library, and the entity path, which you'd have to set in some way.

The nodejs-dialogflow library is just a wrapper around the REST API that you've  also found (actually, probably around the gRPC equivalent, but it doesn't matter). The big thing that it does, however, is the work that will convert the secret key that you get from the service account into an access token that you need to send with every request. If you're not familiar with Google's OAuth 2 implementation, this can make things a lot easier, [although it is certainly possible to do this yourself](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests).

Finally, while the idea is sound and will work, remember that this will take some time during an Intent and that the user is waiting for a reply. Since this data will update infrequently, and for everyone, you may wish to use a [similar API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.entityTypes) to just change the Entity periodically. This process could be something you trigger out of a scheduled (cron) job and have a way to trigger it manually if you need to.

Comment: Hi @Prisoner, Thanks for your detail answer. I didn't get the first paragraph. Can you give some example of it? However confirmation that the 2 libraries can work together give me some hope. I will have a look today on the REST API and try to generate an access token. And finally was thinking about such approach (change the Entity periodically through cron job or manual trigger) but before implementing it was keen to try with Session Entity (just to see what is feasible and what is not) . Cheers

Comment: Answer updated, and hopefully clarified. Since you've accepted the answer, if you do have further problems. posting the code you're trying to use and any errors you're geting as a new question might be best.